# How to launch a default activity based on a given URI?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am able to call an android activity from within Kodi with very specific intent, data uri and package name, but how can I call the default app for twitter, facebook or even a web browser based on any given uri/url?

Example:

```
control.execute('StartAndroidActivity("package_name","android.intent.action.VIEW","","url")')
```

Where package_name could be 'com.google.chrome' and url could be 'http://www.facebook.com'

Is a "generic" package name which I can call and launch a default application or a dialog for selection?

Comment: Wat name 'Kodi' refers to?

Comment: Kodi is a media center which can launch other android apps with a built-in function.

Comment: Which type of file you are using to call this command?

Comment: This command is called from python which calls a built-in function of Kodi which it finally is C++ I think (PythontoCplusplus)